# Adding a rectangular box with tikz to table (beamer)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, beamer

I would like to add a rectangular box to my table to highlight some rows. I'm trying to use `tikz` with the second lot of code from [Harish Kumar's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140224/) to a similar question. However, unlike the earlier question, I'm using `beamer` and the box appears in the wrong place after compiling several times. I'm attaching a picture with the desired result and what I obtain instead.

[image]

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,dcolumn}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit}
\pdfmapfile{+sansmathaccent.map}
\newcolumntype{d}{D..{-1}}

\newcounter{nodecount}
\newcommand\tabnode[1]{\addtocounter{nodecount}{1} \tikz \node                (\arabic{nodecount}) {#1};}

% Some options common to all the nodes and paths
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture,baseline]
\tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt,anchor=base,
minimum width=1.8cm,align=center,text depth=.25ex,outer sep=1.5pt]
\tikzstyle{every path}+=[thick, rounded corners]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title of my slide}
\begin{table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{   
\begin{tabular}{c*{7}{d}}
\midrule 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCCC$} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCC$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCC$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCC$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCCCCC$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCCC$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCCC$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCCCCC$}
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Panel A: AAA}} \\
\midrule
\tabnode{0}     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 &            \tabnode{0.00} \\
\tabnode{}    & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) &          \tabnode{0.00} \\
  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
  0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
  & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\
  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
  0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
  & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\ 
 \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Panel B: BBB}} \\
 \midrule
 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
   & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\
   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
   & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\
   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
 0     & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
   & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\ 
 \midrule
 \end{tabular}
 }
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
 \node[draw=red,rounded corners = 1ex,fit=(1)(4),inner sep = 1pt] {};
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you seen the question [Rectangles around cells in table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140221/rectangles-around-cells-in-table)? It has the perfect solution to yours (and uses the same preamble as yours, did you get it from there?), try the second solution where the accepted answer uses `\tabnode`.

Comment: Alenanno, exactly. I'm currently following the 2nd solution with \tabnode (first two rows of the table). However, I don't get the desired result.

Comment: The second solution has nothing to do with `\tabnode`. It is just another approach. But it seems like you are trying the fist solution. Does your MWE match your current progress and your purpose?

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is a direct duplicate. Are the solutions in the other question compatible with `dcolumn`?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Sorry, you are right. I'm trying the 2nd code of the first solution. Yes, it matches.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate. In the duplicate link, the `\documentclass` is `article`, while here it's `beamer`. Also, in the duplicate there is no need to align numbers by their decimal separator, here yes (they don't align with `\tabnode`, so I had to find a different solution.

Comment: @yo' No they are not, I voted to reopen this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the revised version.

Changes:

1. Fixed your `newcolumntype`. I also had fixed the command for the `\tabnode`, but this solution didn't allow the numbers inside the node to align by the decimal separator so I removed the command altogether and replaced with something else, see below.

   Furthermore, now if you try adding random numbers to your values, they should all be aligned at the separator `.`, I just tested it myself. In the output below, the first number is long and seems not to be aligned, but if you add more numbers in the column, they will be aligned.
2. I used a tweaked version of [Caramdir's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4861/4778) for drawing the rectangle. Basically you need to mark the **top left** with `\marktopleft{a1}` where `a1` is the first shape, for example, and the **bottom right** with `\markbottomright{a1}`.

   Each shape needs to be coupled like that.
3. In case you don't know, `booktabs` supports also `\toprule` and `\bottomrule`. I have added them.

As usual with Tikz, remember that if you add a new rectangle, you might need to typeset twice to fix the positioning.

Here is the output:

[image]

And here is the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit,tikzmark}
\newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{-1}}

\begin{document}

% Some options common to all the nodes and paths
\tikzset{   
        every picture/.style={remember picture,baseline},
        every node/.style={anchor=base,align=center,outer sep=1.5pt},
        every path/.style={thick},
        }

\newcommand\marktopleft[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
        \node (marker-#1-a) at (.1em,.3em) {};%
}
\newcommand\markbottomright[1]{%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
        \node (marker-#1-b) at (.1em,.3em) {};%
    \tikz[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=3pt]
        \node[draw=red,rounded corners,fit=(marker-#1-a.north west) (marker-#1-b.south east)] {};%
}


\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title of my slide}
%
\begin{table}
     \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
%
\begin{tabular}{.*{8}{.}}
    \toprule 
%
\multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCCC$} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCC$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCC$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCC$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCCCCC$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCCC$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCCC$}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{$CCCCCCC$}
\\
    \midrule
\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Panel A: AAA}} \\
    \midrule
  \marktopleft{a1}134,343.50 & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.030 \\
  & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & 12510.00\markbottomright{a1} \\
  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
  0     & 103.00  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.440 \\
  & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (10.00) \\
  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
  \marktopleft{b1}0     & 0.0435  & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
  & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00)\markbottomright{b1} \\
  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
 \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Panel B: BBB}} \\
    \midrule
 0     & 0.00  & 404.00  & 0.34300 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
   & (70.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\
   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
 0     & 32.00  & 0.2300  & 54540.00 & 0.0045 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
   & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\
   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
 0     & 0.00  & 10.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
   & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) & (0.00) \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```