# Why tikzmark doesn't work with beamer class?

Tags: beamer, listings, tikzmark

Consider the following MCE that makes use of:

- `tikzmark` library and its `listings` library that let us add marks to `lstlisting` environments,
- the high level `\balloon` macro (provided by the `tikzmark`'s author in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86457/18401) that puts a fancy node behind certain lines of the code (it is here a bit modified in order to avoid overlapping of the line preceding the first one wanted, see Jellby's comment on Mar 9 '14 at 18:26 in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79787/18401).

The point is, this code works nicely with e.g. the `article` class but not with the `beamer` one: with the latter, the node isn't displayed.

```
% \documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{beamerarticle}
%
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit,calc}
\usetikzmarklibrary{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\tikzset{
  balloon/.style={
    draw,
    fill=blue!20,
    opacity=0.4,
    inner sep=4pt,
    rounded corners=2pt
  },
}
%
\newcommand{\balloon}[4]{%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\firstline{%
    #3-1%
  }%
  \iftikzmark{line-#2-\firstline-start}{%
    \iftikzmark{line-#2-#3-first}{%
      \xdef\blines{($ ({pic cs:line-#2-\firstline-start} -| {pic
          cs:line-#2-#3-first})!.5!({pic cs:line-#2-#3-first}) $)}%
    }{%
      \iftikzmark{line-#2-#3-start}{%
        \xdef\blines{({pic cs:line-#2-\firstline-start} -| {pic
            cs:line-#2-#3-start})}%
      }{%
        \xdef\blines{(pic cs:line-#2-\firstline-start)}%
      }%
    }%
  }{%
    \xdef\blines{}%
  }%
  \foreach \k in {#3,...,#4} {%
    \iftikzmark{line-#2-\k-first}{%
      \xdef\blines{\blines (pic cs:line-#2-\k-first) }%
    }{} \iftikzmark{line-#2-\k-end}{%
      \xdef\blines{\blines (pic cs:line-#2-\k-end) }%
    }{}%
  }%
  \ifx\blines\empty
  \else
  \edef\temp{\noexpand\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    \noexpand\node[fit={\blines},balloon] (#1) {};}%
  \temp
  \fi
}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \balloon{comment}{code}{3}{4}
\begin{lstlisting}[name=code]
Foo Bar Baz
Foo Baz Bar
Bar Foo Baz
Bar Baz Foo
Baz Foo Bar
Baz Bar Foo
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Results

### With `article` (and `beamerarticle`)

[image]

### With `beamer`

[image]

Comment: see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240542/adding-a-rectangular-box-with-tikz-to-table-beamer

Comment: @samcarter Well, I don't see what can help me concerning `beamer` in this question and its answer and comments. Could you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: If you would use `\marktopleft` and `\markbottomright` as escaped code sequences inside your listing?

Comment: @samcarter Indeed, that works. But the nice feature of `tikzmark` library (and its `listings` library) and the `\balloon` macro is that they don't need the listing content to be changed. Therefore they apply to a listing input thanks to `\lstinputlisting`. Currently, I don't see why `\marktopleft` and `\markbottomright` from this question work nicely and not this `\balloon` macro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

beamer redefines `\pgfmark` and adds a number for the slide to the internal name to make if overlay aware. If you look at the aux you can see that you get names like `line-code-6-start-1` instead of `line-code-6-start`. This means that all your `\iftikzmark` fails.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}\usepackage{beamerarticle}
%
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit,calc}
\usetikzmarklibrary{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\tikzset{
  balloon/.style={
    draw,
    fill=blue!20,
    opacity=0.4,
    inner sep=4pt,
    rounded corners=2pt
  },
}

\makeatletter

%
\newcommand{\balloon}[4]{%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\firstline{%
    #3-1%
  }%
  \iftikzmark{line-#2-\firstline-start-\the \beamer@slideinframe}{%
    \iftikzmark{line-#2-#3-first-\the \beamer@slideinframe}{%
      \xdef\blines{($ ({pic cs:line-#2-\firstline-start} -| {pic
          cs:line-#2-#3-first})!.5!({pic cs:line-#2-#3-first}) $)}%
    }{%
      \iftikzmark{line-#2-#3-start-\the \beamer@slideinframe}{%
        \xdef\blines{({pic cs:line-#2-\firstline-start} -| {pic
            cs:line-#2-#3-start})}%
      }{%
        \xdef\blines{(pic cs:line-#2-\firstline-start)}%
      }%
    }%
  }{%
    \xdef\blines{}%
  }%
  \foreach \k in {#3,...,#4} {%
    \iftikzmark{line-#2-\k-first-\the \beamer@slideinframe}{%
      \xdef\blines{\blines (pic cs:line-#2-\k-first) }%
    }{} \iftikzmark{line-#2-\k-end-\the \beamer@slideinframe}{%
      \xdef\blines{\blines (pic cs:line-#2-\k-end) }%
    }{}%
  }%
  \ifx\blines\empty
  \else
  \edef\temp{\noexpand\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    \noexpand\node[fit={\blines},balloon] (#1) {};}%
  \temp
  \fi
}
%
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[fragile]
\balloon{comment}{code}{3}{4}

\begin{lstlisting}[name=code]
Foo Bar Baz
Foo Baz Bar
Bar Foo Baz
Bar Baz Foo
Baz Foo Bar
Baz Bar Foo
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Addition

An alternative to the redefinition of `\ballon` is a redefinition of `\iftikzmark`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\iftikzmark[3]{%
    \@ifundefined{save@pt@#1-\the\beamer@slideinframe}{%
      #3%
    }{%
      #2%
    }%
  }%
```

Comment: Very nice! :) However, is it possible to make the `\balloon` macro overlay aware or, at least , to make it work if given as an argument of e.g. `\only<...>` command?

Comment: About making the `\balloon` macro overlay aware, see for instance http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/351434/18401.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this problem has been fixed upstream by https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark/commit/1427ccaa0be7932d964d3f51b26b5a4d3444e1af or https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark/commit/00141c09c0b53c14459c206dc23ea6ea90f96b0b

So if you use the work-around presented above on a recent TeXlive distribution (I have tried on Ubuntu 19.04 & 19.10 and Debian/unstable) it does not work...
You need now to go back to the first example of this page.

Comment: Hi, as it's possible that your "answer" here will get deleted, can I encourage you to let me know via github  if there's still a problem with tikzmark. The latest version got to ctan only very recently so will take time to get to debian, I expect. I try not to introduce new bugs each time but I'm not always successful!

Comment: With an up to date TeX Live 2019 (vanilla install on a Linux box), the Ulrike's workaround still works like a charm. BTW, your answer would probably better have been a comment.