# pgf error: No shape named ... is known, but only at 1st run

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, listings, tikzmark

(This question extend [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/351434/18401).)

The following MCE:

1. at its 1<sup>st</sup> compilation, leads to a:

   > Package pgf Error: No shape named comment is known.
2. if the 1<sup>st</sup> compilation is run without stopping, works like a charm at the subsequent ones (at its 3<sup>rd</sup> one, all the cross-references are right and the resulting PDF file is as expected).

Do you know how to make this example run smoothly at 1<sup>st</sup> compilation?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{%
  tikzmark,fit,calc,%
  positioning
}

\usetikzmarklibrary{listings}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\iftikzmark[3]{%
  \@ifundefined{save@pt@#1-\the\beamer@slideinframe}{%
    #3%
  }{%
    #2%
  }%
}%
\newcommand{\@balloon}[4]{%
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\@firstline{%
    #3-1%
  }%
  \iftikzmark{line-#2-\@firstline-start}{%
    \iftikzmark{line-#2-#3-first}{%
      \xdef\@blines{%
        ($ ({pic cs:line-#2-\@firstline-start} -| {pic
          cs:line-#2-#3-first})!.5!({pic cs:line-#2-#3-first}) $)%
      }%
    }{%
      \iftikzmark{line-#2-#3-start}{%
        \xdef\@blines{%
          ({pic cs:line-#2-\@firstline-start} -| {pic cs:line-#2-#3-start})%
        }%
      }{%
        \xdef\@blines{(pic cs:line-#2-\@firstline-start)}%
      }%
    }%
  }{%
    \xdef\@blines{}%
  }%
  \foreach \k in {#3,...,#4} {%
    \iftikzmark{line-#2-\k-first}{%
      \xdef\@blines{%
        \@blines (pic cs:line-#2-\k-first)%
      }%
    }{}%
    \iftikzmark{line-#2-\k-end}{%
      \xdef\@blines{%
        \@blines (pic cs:line-#2-\k-end)%
      }%
    }{}%
  }%
  \ifx\@blines\empty%
  \else%
  \edef\temp{%
    \noexpand\tikz[remember picture,overlay]%
    \noexpand\node[fit={\@blines},draw] (#1) {};%
  }%
  \temp%
  \fi%
}
%
\newcommand<>{\balloon}[4][code\the\beamer@slideinframe]{%
  \alt#5{\@balloon{#2}{#1}{#3}{#4}}{\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\path (0,0);}%
}
%
\lstnewenvironment{hllisting}[1][]{%
  \lstset{name=code\the\beamer@slideinframe,#1}%
}{%
  \lstset{name=}%
}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{hllisting}
1st line of code
2nd line of code
3rd line of code
4th line of code
5th line of code
6th line of code
\end{hllisting}
\balloon{comment}{2}{3}%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] {
  \node[right=of comment] () {Foo};%
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Imho it should work if you add suitable nodes in the alternative pathes, that means after `\ifx@blines\empty` there should be a `\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node(#1){};` and in the balloon definition also in the branch with the `\tikz` command (with #2).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed, though the 1st addition seems to be enough (I must admit I don't understand the 2nd one you suggested :) Would you mind make this comment an answer?

Comment: In your example the first is enough. But there must exist a case where the second argument of \alt is used (or you wouldn't need it at all) and so it is safer to add the node there too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add suitable nodes in the alternative pathes, that means after

```
 \ifx@blines\empty
```

there should be a

```
 \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node(#1){};
```

and in the balloon definition also in the branch with the `\tikz` command (in this case with #2 instead of #1).

Comment: For the 2nd part, do you mean to replace `\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\path (0,0);` by `\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node(#2){};` in `\alt#5{\@balloon{#2}{#1}{#3}{#4}}{\tikz[overlay,remember picture]\path (0,0);}`?

Comment: I don't remember why there is a zero path, but imho an empty node there should work too.