# Tikz: error when using beamer-class but not when using article-class

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-matrix, tikz-shape

I'm using Overleaf to build a beamer presentation and wanted to add rectangles around cells in table (as described in [this other question/answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140221/rectangles-around-cells-in-table) by barbara beeton). Unfortunately, I **get error** messages and disaligned rectangles **when** I try to **implement it in beamer, *inside* the frame** environment.

Here it is a minimal *working* example using the **article** class:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
          \matrix (M) [%
            matrix of nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm
          ]
          {%
             A1& B1 \\
             A2& B2 \\
         };
        \node[draw=blue,rounded corners = 1ex,fit=(M-1-1)(M-2-1),inner sep = 0pt] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here it is a minimal *working* example using the **beamer** class:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit}
\begin{document}
% \begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
          \matrix (M) [%
            matrix of nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm
          ]
          {%
             A1& B1 \\
             A2& B2 \\
         };
        \node[draw=blue,rounded corners = 1ex,fit=(M-1-1)(M-2-1),inner sep = 0pt] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
% \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, if I uncomment the frame environment the code does not compile properly anymore. The following is the *problematic* code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
          \matrix (M) [%
            matrix of nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm
          ]
          {%
             A1& B1 \\
             A2& B2 \\
         };
        \node[draw=blue,rounded corners = 1ex,fit=(M-1-1)(M-2-1),inner sep = 0pt] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: You didn't say which error, is it this one? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15093/single-ampersand-used-with-wrong-catcode-error-using-tikz-matrix-in-beamer

Comment: Alternatively https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208408/tikz-matrix-undefined-control-sequence

Comment: It's the second error, that is: ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pgf@matrix@last@nextcell@options

Comment: You should realize that beamer and article have almost nothing in common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add option `fragile` to frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,fit, matrix, shapes,}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]% <---
\frametitle{Frame Title}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
          \matrix (M) [
            matrix of nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm
          ]
          {
             A1& B1 \\
             A2& B2 \\
         };
        \node[draw=blue,rounded corners = 1ex,fit=(M-1-1)(M-2-1),inner sep = 0pt] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you think those options have anything to with it? With or without them, the error is the same. See e.g. the question I linked to above or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208408/tikz-matrix-undefined-control-sequence

Comment: @TorbjørnT., because with fragile it works fine (no errors). Frankly said, it might be, that I confused something, i.e. that actually problem is with  ampersands.

Comment: You didn't understand what I said. In your answer you say that `fragile` is required *because of* `matrix of nodes, column sep=1cm, row sep=1cm`. That is wrong.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., i delete this part of explanation, I need to check again some my older solution of similar problems.